# ng-bootstrap datepicker range. How to set toDate automatic

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Right now if i click fromDate then toDate is null.

Whatever is the initial day clicked in fromDate, i want to add 2 days of range and then thats the value of toDate but if I want to add more range to toDate then that also should be possible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wudwqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-range.html
I tried fiddling in onDateSelection function in the stackblitz demo but couldn't get it to work.